# Rubyの繰り返し処理について

Tags: ruby

Rubyの繰り返し処理において，以下のコードをより速く実行できるように書き直す方法はありますでしょうか．

宜しくお願いいたします．

```
※ resiSiPower.length == out.lengthである
(0 ... out.length).each do |j|
  resiSiPower[j] += (out[j].abs)**2
end
```

（追加の質問）
Rubyで実行が遅くなるのは繰り返し処理によるものであると私自身は考えているのですが（インタプリタ言語であるのは理解しています），その中でも繰り返し処理を速く記述するコツがあれば教えて頂きたいです．

Comment: 確認ですけれども、`out[j]` は複素数(complex number)でしょうか？

Comment: @metropolis はい．複素数です．

Comment: `(out[j].abs)**2` は絶対値の2乗なので、`sqrt(out[j].real ** 2 + out[j].imag ** 2) ** 2` ということになります。つまり、`out[j].real ** 2 + out[j].imag ** 2` に書き替えることができます(高速化に寄与するかどうかは分かりませんが…)。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ruby 2.6.0p0 (2018-12-25 revision 66547) [x86_64-linux]で下記コードを実行し、速度を検証しました。

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

require 'benchmark'
require 'parallel'
require 'numo/narray'
require 'nmatrix'

list_size = 1_000_000
range = (-100.0..100.0)
out = Array.new(list_size) do
  rand(range) + rand(range) * 1i
end
resiSiPower = Array.new(list_size) do
  rand(range)**2
end

# Numo::NArray
out_na = Numo::DComplex.new(list_size)
out_na.store(out)
resiSiPower_na = Numo::DFloat.new(list_size)
resiSiPower_na.store(resiSiPower)

# NMatrix
out_nm = N[out, dtype: :complex128]
resiSiPower_nm = N[resiSiPower, dtype: :float64]

Benchmark.bm(23) do |x|
  x.report('orginal') do
    (0...out.length).each do |j|
      resiSiPower[j] += out[j].abs**2
    end
  end
  x.report('r^2 + i^2') do
    (0...out.length).each do |j|
      resiSiPower[j] += out[j].real**2 + out[j].imag**2
    end
  end
  x.report('abs2') do
    (0...out.length).each do |j|
      resiSiPower[j] += out[j].abs2
    end
  end
  x.report('times abs2') do
    out.length.times do |j|
      resiSiPower[j] += out[j].abs2
    end
  end
  x.report('upto abs2') do
    0.upto(out.length - 1) do |j|
      resiSiPower[j] += out[j].abs2
    end
  end
  x.report('zip map abs2 map sum') do
    resiSiPower = resiSiPower.zip(out.map(&:abs2)).map(&:sum)
  end
  x.report('map abs2 zip map sum') do
    resiSiPower = out.map(&:abs2).zip(resiSiPower).map(&:sum)
  end
  x.report('each_with_index map') do
    resiSiPower = resiSiPower.each_with_index.map do |r, i|
      r + out[i].abs2
    end
  end
  x.report('map! with i') do
    i = 0
    resiSiPower.map! do |r|
      r + out[i].abs2
      i += 1
    end
  end
  x.report('map with each') do
    out_e = out.each
    resiSiPower.map! do |r|
      r + out_e.next.abs2
    end
  end
  x.report('parallel') do
    resiSiPower = Parallel.map(0...out.length, in_threads: 4) do |j|
      resiSiPower[j] + out[j].abs2
    end
  end
  x.report('Numo::NArray') do
    resiSiPower_na += out_na.abs**2
  end
  x.report('NMatrix') do
    resiSiPower_nm += out_nm.abs**2
  end
end
```

実行前に`gem install parallel numo-narray nmatrix`として必要なライブラリをインストールしておいてください。

`out`を浮動小数点数複素数の配列、`resiSiPower`を浮動小数点数の配列という前提にしています。型が異なる場合は、違いが出るかも知れませんので、それに合わせて修正してください。また、OSやRubyのバージョンによる違いも出る場合があります。

### 絶対値の2乗の求め方

絶対値の2乗の場合は[Complex#abs2](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/latest/method/Complex/i/abs2.html)が利用できます。と言っても、`x.real**2 + x.imag**2`と速度はほとんど変わりませんでした。どちらか好みを使うときでしょう。

### ループの回し方

`(0...n).each`は`n.times`や`0.upto(n-1)`とも書けます。これらも速度はほとんど変わりませんでしたので、好みを使うときでしょう。

代入ではなく[Array#map!](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/latest/method/Array/i/collect=21.html)を使う方法もありますが、インデックスを別途増加させる必要があります。こちらも`(0...n).each`とほとんど変わりませんでした。インデックスではなく`each`でEnumeratorを作る方法は逆に遅くなりました。

その他、関数型プログラミング風に`zip`や`map`を組み合わせて使う方法は配列の生成があるため遅くなります。

### 並列化

CRubyにはGVLがあるため単純なマルチスレッドにしても遅くなるだけでした。ただ、JRubyではマルチスレッドが並列化するため、速くなる可能性はあります(未検証)。

マルチプロセスはそれぞれのプロセスをまとめる処理があるせいか、遅すぎて計測できませんでした。ただ、配列を適当な数に分割してマルチプロセスで処理した場合は早くなる可能性はあります(未検証)。

### 行列ライブラリの使用

Pythonでいうnumpyのようなライブラリとして、[Numo::NArray](https://github.com/ruby-numo/numo-narray)と[NMatrix](https://github.com/SciRuby/nmatrix)があります。これらはマトリックス(ベクトル含む)をマトリックスのまま計算することが出来ます。内部処理はCレベルで実装されており、それぞれの要素に対して同じ処理を高速に行うことが出来ます。

Numo::NArrayは大幅に速度が向上しました。高速を目指すのであれば、Numo::NArrayを使うのが一番いいかもしれません。

NMatrixは逆に遅くなりました。何故かはわかりません。(私のコードの書き方が悪いのでしょうか？)

---

以上の事から、今のからあまり変えずに少しでも速くするなら`abs2`を使う。さらに速度の向上を目指すならNumo::NArrayを使うというのがいいのではないでしょうか。

Comment: 大変詳しく検証していただき誠にありがとうございます．現在，わたくしはRubyでシミュレータを書いてまして，ベクトルや行列は全て`Array.new`で記述しています．`Numo::NArray`は大幅に速度が向上するとのことですが，例えば一部を`Numo::NArray`にした場合，`Array.new`との互換性はありますでしょうか．

Comment: `Numo::NArray`は特定の数値型(Cでいう`int`や`double`等) **のみ** で構成されたサイズ固定の多次元配列しか扱えず、それらの処理に特化しています。高速である分、Arrayのような汎用性はなく、互換性はありません。

Comment: ここでのArrayの汎用性とはどのようなことですか...（Ruby始めて間もないのでまだ理解が浅いです）

Comment: `Numo::NArray`は作成時に指定した数値型以外は入れられません。例えば整数(int32等)の配列として作った場合、浮動小数点数や複素数、文字列等は入れられないと言うことです。他にも数値以外、例えば文字列の配列も作れません。対して、`Array`は整数でも浮動小数点数でも文字列でもどのようなオブジェクトも入れることが出来ます。また、オブジェクトの型(クラス)を統一する必要もありません。つまり、あらゆるものの配列として使えると言うことで、汎用性があると言うことです。